# Drop $n$ random circles inside a square without overlap

Tags: probability, geometry

The problem: find the size $l$ of a square such that $n$ circles with radius $r$ dropped randomly inside it will overlap with probability $t$.

I'm writing a graph visualization tool, and would like to drop graph's nodes randomly inside a square with little probability of overlap ($t = 1\%$).

What have I tried: The square area is $A = l^2$, and each circle have area $a = \pi r^2$. I view the problem as a [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), where there are $f = A/a$ slots, and each circle is assigned one randomly. The probability of collision is

$$ p = \left(1 - \frac{1}{f}\right)^{n \choose 2} \approx~ e^{-n^2/2f} $$

As I want $p < t$, I get

$$ e^{-n^2/2f} ~<~ t \\ f > \frac{n^2}{2 \log 1/t}$$

Finally, substituting the areas expression, I get

$$ \frac{l^2}{\pi r^2} > \frac{n^2}{2 \log 1/t} \\ l > \frac{nr}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2 \pi}{\log 1/t}} $$

Unfortunately, this does not work as expected: with $n=9$, $r=7$ and $t=0.01$, I get a size of 36, which produces the following image with lots of overlap.

[image: example with multiple overlaps]

I revised my equations and believe there's no mistake there. The fault must be in the birthday paradox assumption, but can't rethink about the problem to tackle it.

Comment: No, that's the probability of *not* having a collision. The probability of collision is $1-p<t$, and that gives $l<\frac{nr}2\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\log(1/(1-t))}}$, which is about $787.6$ for your numbers.

Comment: You are right, silly me! Please write this comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: It seems $t = 0.01$ is too strict. Image obtained with the revised equation and $t=0.1$ for the interested: http://imgur.com/qtJd8tV